# Laravel problem with cache file when deploy to heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, caching

My application is using laravel 8. I deploy it from github to heroku and I want to run the command below:

```
php artisan optimize
```

But I don't know how to run the command in heroku and if the command creates cache files in my app then heroku will delete them after specific time because they are not permanently files deployed from github. Anyone know how to deal with this pls tell me what to do. Thank you!

P/s: i tried to do like the link below but it didn't create any cache file in my app. https://dev.to/autoidle/laravel-deployment-optimization-on-heroku-1hkc

[new update] Problem solved. Just follow the link above and my answer below.

Comment: Why did you remove the previous question and repost it?

Comment: @GertB. sorry for the inconvenient but my thread was closed because it was not clear( idk why) and i can not reopen it to receive the answer although i tried to edit the post. That was the first time i ask in stackoverflow.

Comment: If the post is closed because it was not clear, you should NOT just repost it. At least change it to make it clear.

Comment: you can run commands on Heroku this way: `heroku run /app/php/bin/php /app/www/artisan optimize`

Comment: @GertB. i did edit the thread to make it more clear, like the new thread. But it still tell me that the thread was closed after more than 30 minutes. Because it will not receive the answer but only the comment. Can you tell me how long the thread will reopen if i edit the question so next time i dont have to repost. Sorry again ;(

Comment: it said bash: /app/php/bin/php: No such file or directory.

Comment: i run the command you said in the "run console" of my app

Comment: `heroku run php ... ` looks like the path is not needed anymore. It's been a while since i've used Heroku

Comment: go to APP or (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/app-name)-> click on more -> select run console -> add php artisan command name

Comment: @svikramjeet  i tried it before and it didnt create any cache file in my app

Comment: [new update] the way to cache config follow the link above does create cache file. The only thing i care right now is will heroku remove those cache files after a specific time or not. i will wait and update info later (or anyone know the answer pls tell me) Thank you!

Comment: I thought you have read about Heroku, but you are 100% right about Heroku deleting files that are pushed after creating slug

Comment: @svikramjeet i did read herroku document, that 's why i afraid herroku will remove the cache files in no time. But i still hope there is an exception or somthing about this situation. Because if 's not, how devloper will deploy laravel application to herroku and run it without any cache config? :(.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: @svikramjeet Gert B. Thank you both for helping me. I think i got my answer by my self, will update the thread soon

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[new update] You can follow the link below and do exactly the same but you need to fix the part of Procfile from **composer warmup** to **composer run-script warmup**. That will solve the problem in this thread.
https://dev.to/autoidle/laravel-deployment-optimization-on-heroku-1hkc

composer.json:

```
    "scripts": {
       ...
       "warmup": [
           "@php artisan config:cache",
           "@php artisan route:cache",
           "@php artisan view:cache"
    ]
},
```

Procfile:

```
web: composer run-script warmup && heroku-php-apache2
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCtKL.png)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container-based systems, such as Docker, operate.

The solution to your problem is to use Redis as cache (and also for session, queue, ...)

1. Add to your Heroku environments:
   `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`
2. `composer require ext-json`
3. Install Redis as add-on for example: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis

Comment: Thank you. This will help me a lot in the future. But in this thread i found an easier way to solve the problem.  I edited the answer few secs ago.